# Django hits the database for each filter() call

Tags: database, django, performance, django-queryset

I have some Django 1.3 code that looks up many model instances in a loop, ie.

```
my_set = myinstance.subitem_set.all()

for value in values:
  existing = my_set.filter(attr_name=value)
  if len(existing) == 1:
     ...
```

This works, but profiling SQL queries shows that it hits the DB on each iteration. According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/ iterating over the related items should eagerly load them, so I tried calling:

```
list(my_set)
```

However, this doesn't help. It does do a query to load all the sub-items, but then it still does an individual query for each sub-item inside the loop. How do I get it to use the cached set and not hit the DB each time? The DB is PostgreSQL 8.4.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in this line:

```
if len(existing) == 1:
```

From Django documentation:

> len(). A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you might expect, returns the length of the result list.
>
> Note: Don't use len() on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set. It's much more efficient to handle a count at the database level, using SQL's SELECT COUNT(*), and Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason. See count() below.

So in your case it executes the query each time when you call `len(existing)`. The more effective way is:

```
existing.count() == 1
```

This will also hit the database each time you call it but it will execute `SELECT COUNT(*)` which is faster.

Comment: Thanks, but the whole point of the question is that I don't want it to hit the database each time - I want it to read the entire set into memory and use that.

Comment: Then you shouldn't rely on Django QuerySets. Do `my_set = list(my_set)`. You'll get a regular Python list which you can work with, but you won't be  able to use `.filter()` and other QuerySet stuff in that case.

Comment: Of course, if there is no built-in way then I'll have to do that (probably a `dict` instead of a `list`), but I was hoping Django would be smart enough to handle this.

Comment: @EMP Filter transfroms to SQL expression which is executed by your DB. You was hoping Django would process SQL without DB?

Comment: I was hoping it would process a method call without DB when there is no need for the DB. That it uses SQL is an implementation detail.